# MVC Contrib Input Builders and Spark View Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine, mvccontrib

In Eric Hexter's [Input Builders](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/hex/archive/2009/06/09/opinionated-input-builders-for-asp-net-mvc-using-partials-part-i.aspx), different templates use different strongly-typed models; for example `String` uses `PropertyViewModel<object>`, `DateTime` uses `PropertyViewModel<DateTime>`, `Form` uses `PropertyViewModel[]`, and so forth. [Spark View Engine](http://sparkviewengine.com/) doesn't seem to allow this, because all elements that compose the presentation (masters, views, partials, etc.) are compiled into a single class.

If I try to setup a view involving more than one template, I get the following exception:

`Only one viewdata model can be declared. PropertyViewModel<DateTime> != PropertyViewModel<object>`

If leave just one viewdata declaration, I get another exception about the passed model item mismatching the required one.

It seems like I will have to give up either the Input Builders or Spark, which is sad because I really love both. So I thought I'd ask here to see if anybody has already figured this out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use <% Html.RenderPartial() %> for partial view rendering with different model. This will create more than one view class.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not calling the partials directly; they are called by the InputBuilder assembly so I don't think I have control over that.